# scipy probability density function not giving correct value

Tags: python, statistics, scipy, probability-density

I've following code-

```
import scipy.stats as scipystats
print(scipystats.distributions.norm.pdf(1384, 1384, 373))
```

which prints output of `0.0010695503496` which doesn't make sense to me. 
What I am trying to do is calculate value of PDF at 1384 given mean of 1384 and std. deviation of 373. I would expect value of PDF at 1384 to be close to 1 as it lies exactly on mean. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see is normalization.

```
>>> import scipy.stats as stats
>>> stats.norm.pdf(1384, 1384, 373)
0.0010695503496016962
>>> stats.norm.pdf(0, 0, 373)
0.0010695503496016962
>>> 
>>> 1 / np.sqrt(2.*np.pi) / 373
0.0010695503496016962
```

With a unit variance:

```
>>> stats.norm.pdf(0, 0, 1)
0.3989422804014327
>>> stats.norm.pdf(1384, 1384, 1)
0.3989422804014327
>>> 1/np.sqrt(2*np.pi)
0.3989422804014327
```

See [an explicit formula in eg wikipedia](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution)

Comment: can you please further explain what is happening under the hood?I googled unit variance but couldn't find relevant information.

Comment: Wikipedia has an explicit formula

Comment: actually I am wondering why the value in unit variance is .398 and not 1? intuitively, PDF should be 1 around mean, right?

Comment: No. PDF must integrate to one, that's it. There is no restriction of the value of PDF at any particular point. For instance, think of a uniform distribution on (a, b).